# xcode 1.5 stuck on the "new user" screen

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm on an iBook G3 Clamshell with Mac os X 10.3.9 with 512 Mb RAM installed. I've installed Xcode 1.5. When started, the "new user" screen is displayed but unresponsive. I have to "Force quit".
Interface Builder is working fine though.

[image]

Comment: xcode 1.5 ? sure

Comment: yes Xcode 1.5 - I'm targeting iBook G3 with Panther. 
Xcode 1.5 is the only choice for mac osx 10.3.9.

Comment: I am wondering you how you are supporting the latest ios using that

Comment: IOS ? there is nothing relative to IOS in my request. I'm using an old Xcode version to develop cocoa apps for Panther.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance